# How to call a function exactly after 60 minutes?

Tags: qt

I have a function for 'shutdown' operation. Now i need to call this function, exactly after 60 minutes.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a QTimer::singleShot set for 60 minutes should do the trick.

Comment: I done like this,
timer->setInterval(3600000);
QObject::connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(systemShutdown()));
timer->start();
This is working now!!